# Element won't slideDown() on certain width viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to achieve a footer similar to what https://www.gucci.com/ has, where it becomes an accordion on below 768px and becomes normal block grid on 768px and above.

My issue is that every-time after I toggle the accordion below 768px then resize it back above 768px the elements won't slideDown or show, it'll just stay folded or hidden.

below are my code

```js
$(document).on('click','.footer-toggle', function(e){
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    if($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
        $(this).removeClass("opened");
        $(this).next(".toggled-content").slideUp("fast");
      } else {
        $(".footer-toggle").removeClass("opened");
        $(".toggled-content").slideUp("fast");
        $(this).addClass("opened");
        $(this).next(".toggled-content").slideDown("fast");
    }
  }
e.preventDefault();
});
  
if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
  $('.toggle-content').slideDown("fast");
}
```

```css
.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="footer-toggle">TITLE 1</a>
<div class="toggle-content">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="">NAV A</a></li>
      <li><a href="">NAV B</a></li>
      <li><a href="">NAV C</a></li>
      <li><a href="">NAV D</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate the help guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work with just a couple changes. Here's what I'd suggest:

1. Clean up your references to class names in your jQuery selectors (i.e. where the class 'toggle-content' is referenced as 'toggled-content').
2. Remove these 2 lines just inside your `else` block.

   ```
   $(".footer-toggle").removeClass("opened");
   $(".toggled-content").slideUp("fast");
   ```

These are working against you in this case, where you want the menu to slide down, but your code is first telling it to slide up.

Comment: my bad for the typo. my issue is just during resize now that it wont slideDown so that it'll show contents

Comment: I see. IIUC, you want the menu to slide open when resizing above 767 by default? Since the resizing is done via JavaScript (or in this case jQuery), you'd have to place that final `if` block in an event handler. jQuery's [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) would work well.